# Map a field from a property class as the database column value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-4.0, nhibernate-mapping

```
public class MyRefClass
{
    ...
    string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}


public class MyPersistedClass
{
    public virtual MyRefClass { get; set; }
}
```

Say I have a reference class type as a property of my persisted class.  If I have no need to store the full detail of the reference class, just the name so that it can be reloaded via the name when the persisted class is loaded (hydrated)...

Given a mechanism similar to the way NHibernate stores enums as strings using the NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType mapping how would I go about doing something similar for a different object type.

```
<key-property name="MyEnumType" type="NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType`1[[MyEnumTypeDomain.MyEnumType, MyEnumTypeAssembly]], NHibernate"/>
```

What class or Interface would I need to implement to allow me to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to provide your own implementation of IUserType (see http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/10/15/mapping-different-types-iusertype.aspx)

The important bits are NullSafeGet (where you construct your object from the database) and NullSafeSet (where you convert your object into a value to store in the database)

Comment: Thanks, another link for this is at http://thesenilecoder.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/nhibernate-samples-row-versioning-with.html